# My iOS app takes a lot of time to bring back to front

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am working on an iOS game with `cocos2d-x` and it takes a lot of time to go back to the foreground after pushing it in the background.
When I want to bring my app back it freezes for about 5 or 6 seconds before being responsive again.

I put breakpoints in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` in my `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation. They are only triggered after the freeze is finished.

Do you have any idea of the reason an app can take a lot of time to bring back to front ?

Any similar experience with cocos2d-x which can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the background transition not in the foreground. When the player brings back to the game the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method did not finished to process and it caused a freeze. I have to optimize this method.